# Stopping a CSS animation but letting its current iteration finish

Tags: css, animation

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="rotate"></div>​
```

And the following CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration:         5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  linear;
}​
```

I want to know if there is a way (using JavaScript) to stop the animation but let it finish its current iteration (preferably by changing one or a few CSS properties). I have tried setting `-webkit-animation-name` to have a blank value but that causes the element to jump back to its original position in a jarring fashion. I have also tried setting `-webkit-animation-iteration-count` to `1` but that does the same thing.

Comment: As an alternative, I suggest a javascript animation.

Comment: computing the current iteration and setting the iteration count to that value, is it possible/trackable?

Comment: Try making another class for the div that styles it to be in the position you want it to finish in, and then using javascript, apply that class to the div right when the animation reaches the point you want it to stop.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Stop the animation upon receiving an `animationiteration` event. Something like this (using jQuery):

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.rotate.anim {
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration:         5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:  linear;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rotate anim">TEST</div>
<input id="stop" type="submit" value="stop it" />
```

**JS (JQuery)**

```
$("#stop").click(function() {
    $(".rotate").one('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function() {
        this.classList.remove("anim");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmp2fakn/

Note that I'm using `.one` here (not `.on`) so that the handler only runs once. That way, the animation can later be restarted.

Comment: I made a version which can also restart the animation on request. The event handler for the `animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration` events has to be disabled after it is fired. http://jsfiddle.net/MNQcN/1/

Comment: Actually, that's why I used `.one()` in my original code (which you changed). `.one()` binds a one-time event handler. Using `one`: http://jsfiddle.net/MNQcN/3/

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought that was an error. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why doesn't this work with SVG? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Marathon55/y2b7fg5r/

Comment: For some reason, jQuery does not allow you to add/remove classes on SVG elements (see https://martinwolf.org/before-2018/blog/2014/12/adding-and-removing-classes-from-svg-elements-with-jquery/, for example). The workaround is to use something like `this.classList.remove("anim");` instead of `removeClass`. Since `classList` is now quite widely usable, I've updated my answer to use that. I confirmed that the fix works with your example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want the animation to stop where it is when it ends without jumping back to its original position?

Then you want:

***Animate something moving from one place to another and have it stay there:
animation-fill-mode:forwards;***

check this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is coming to this later, here is my solution in React using

```
const [animationPlaying, setAnimationPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);

...

<div
   onAnimationIteration={() => {
          // do 1 more full animation before ending
          if (condition) {
            setAnimationPlaying(false);
          }
        }}
    style={{
        animation: `${customAnimation} 1s infinite`,
        animationPlayState: animationPlaying ? 'running' : 'paused',
    }}

/>
```