# Smooth animation stop

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

When checkbox is checked the `div` is jumping. When you uncheck the checkbox - the `div` immediately moves to initial position.

Is it possible to complete the last animation iteration smoothly and stop after that using only CSS without JS?

```css
#jumping-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1) translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(0.8) translateY(-70%);
  }
}
#toggle:checked ~ #jumping-div {
  animation-name: jump;
  animation-duration: 2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"><label for="toggle">jump</label>
<div id="jumping-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible without JS.
What you can do with CSS is that the animation will be paused by unchecking the checkbox and continues if you check the box again:

```
#toggle:checked ~ #jumping-div {
  animation-play-state:running;
}

#jumping-div {
  animation-play-state:paused;
  animation-name: jump;
  animation-duration: 2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

If you want to finish on animation you may use the solution WITH JS that was discussed here:
[Stopping a CSS animation but letting its current iteration finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061209/stopping-a-css-animation-but-letting-its-current-iteration-finish)