# CSS3 Stop Animation Smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have one css class for moving the ball up and down infinity.

```css
.active_animation {
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.paused_animation {
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="active_animation">Ball</div>
```

The animation is working fine, but when I try to used jquery to pause(By adding pause_animation to ball) this animation I could not move it to another location.

and If I try to remove the .active_animation class, it won't stop smoothly.

My question is how can I paused the animation and have ability to move that ball?

Please help!!!

Comment: For advanced animations it's better to use some animation library. Something like https://greensock.com/tweenmax

Comment: Take a look at this post [stopping css animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061209/stopping-a-css-animation-but-letting-its-current-iteration-finish)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to make your animation depend upon another variable, have a transition applied on this one, and then change the value of the second variable

For instance, you can make a transform: translateY depend on the height of the element (setting it with percentages), and then set the height to 0:

```js
function stop () {
    var ele = document.getElementById('adapter');
    if (ele.style.height == '0%') {
        ele.style.height = '100%';
    } else {
        ele.style.height = '0%';
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
 border: solid 1px green;
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
}

#adapter {
 height: 100%;
 transition: height 2s;
 animation: bounce 4s infinite alternate linear;
}

#div1 {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: bisque;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes bounce {
 from {transform: translateY(0%);}
 to {transform: translateY(100%);}
}

button {
 position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="adapter">
        <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="stop();">Stop</button>
```