# CSS animation suddenly ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I created a spinner animation. On click on spinner, JS adds class **"loading"** and it starts rotating. But if I **remove this class** it returns to the previous position without animation.

I tried to use this:
`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, but result was the same.

There is my CSS:

```
.loading {
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes spin{
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<i class="material-icons refresh-icon" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('loading');">refresh</i>
```

Comment: Well, without that class you have no animation at all assigned to the element. It’s the normal behaviour… so, what’s the problem?

Comment: can you post the JS as well? in that you could just alter the animation-play-state

Comment: @aprouja1 This is the only js, which interact with it

Comment: You need to wait for `animationiteration`. Check this answer for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061553/3515645

Comment: instead of adding/removing animation use `animation-play-state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I did it using JS and **animationiteration** event.

HTML:

```
<div class="spinner">
    <i class="material-icons refresh-icon" onclick="spinner(this)">refresh</i>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const spinner = el => {
    if($(el).hasClass('lock')) return;

    if($(el).hasClass('loading')){
        $(el).addClass('lock').one('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration', function() {
            $(el).removeClass('loading').removeClass('lock');
        });
    }else{
        $(el).addClass('loading');
    }
}
```

Link to codepan: https://codepen.io/nenazarko/pen/zYGPoZy